# Move all files inside sub folders to parent folder

Tags: files, rename

Let's say I have a path like this

```
/x/xx/file
```

I want to move all files inside sub folders of `/x/` to `/x/` at the same time. Is this possible?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

The subfolders have different names, and I want to move all files inside a subfolder no matter the depth, to `/x/`. Also it's possible that I'll have spare files inside `/x/` that are not in any sub folder. No files should go above `/x/` no matter what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move to target folder and execute:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec mv {} . \;
```

with `-mindepth 2` it will search recursively without including the current directory.

Comment: It will search inside any subfolders inside `x` given your example...

Comment: With GNU tools `find ...-exec mv -t . {} +` may be slightly faster (less calls on `mv`)

Answer (score 0):

This works depending on the number of child directories

```
mv */* .
```

Comment: This works great, but not for files starting with a dot

Answer (score 0):

this python script should do the job on windows:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

# Pause for a few seconds to give you time to switch to the window you want to automate
time.sleep(10)
print("10sec")

while True:
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    print("Pressed Enter key")
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
    print("Pressed Ctrl+A keys")
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'x')
    print("Pressed Ctrl+X keys")
    pyautogui.press('backspace')
    print("Pressed Backspace key")
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
    print("Pressed Ctrl+V keys")
    pyautogui.press('delete')
    print("Pressed Delete key")
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    print("Pressed Enter key")
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('right')
    print("Pressed Right Arrow key")
    pyautogui.press('left')
    print("Pressed Left Arrow key")

    # Listen for the Esc key press and stop the script if detected
    if keyboard.is_pressed('Esc'):
        break
```

note: it also deletes the subfolder

Comment: Those print statements might want to state what the keyboard shortcut is expected to do. Eg "Ctrl-x: Cut all files from the folder". This script could also be quite dangerous out of context if you do not switch to the right folder explorer window within 10 seconds.